# Problems using Modernizr with Chrome (automatic adding of 'video' class to HTML breaks it!)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, symfony, modernizr

I'm trying to use Modernizr to do some feature detection on a project.  It's' a large PHP system built in Symfony -- not sure if that's relevant --

In any case, when I add Modernizr the layout breaks.  I tracked it down the following — when it starts up Modernizr sets  class to be

```
class=" js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache"
```

I tracked it down to the 'video' class -- when I take it out, Chrome works fine.

Any clues -- as to cause and how to use Modernizr here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you have a `.video` class in your own css. If you are not using the `video` test from Modernizr, build a custom version of it at http://modernizr.com/download. If you *are* using that test, then just rename your css class from `.video` to anything else